# How can I see the jobs I applied to in Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I got a call for an interview for a position and I wanted to review the job requirements etc. How do I see the history of companies I applied to?

Comment: The site for Careers support, according to [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support), is http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to your **messages** (upper right corner), and then go to the **Sent** folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/sent/applications

Comment: This is no longer true; I have at least three applications I submitted which are not showing in this section. I've confirmed this by looking in my email and at least one has a confirmation email, but has nothing showing in my 'messages' (at all - sent or otherwise).

Answer (score 65):

### Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/sent) .

Don't forget to come back to assess this answer

Comment: :) very nice...

Comment: thanks for the link :) glad that I came back easily to up vote :)

Comment: This is no longer true; I have at least three applications I submitted which are not showing in this section. I've confirmed this by looking in my email and at least one has a confirmation email, but has nothing showing in my 'messages' (at all - sent or otherwise).

Comment: Whew...they should make this more accessible. Profile > Jobs > Tiny Envelope button in upper right > Sent.

Comment: This link still works, upvoted. :-)

Answer (score 20):

You should follow these steps.

[image]

Hope this would help you.

Comment: I'm not quite following this. It looks like the UI changed. But following the link <https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/sent> worked perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Just go to this link : [StackOverflow Jobs - Sent Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/sent)

Answer (score 2):

From stackoverflow.com:

1. Click on the jobs link on the upper left hand side
2. Click the envelope icon in the upper right corner (down a little bit)
3. Click on Inbox (next to "All" and "Applications"). It should show a drop down
4. Click on Sent

This isn't intuitive at all. It was hard to find the envelope icon. It was hard to know to click the word "Inbox".

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is old. StackOverflow has its new interface now where you can find the messages or application as follows.

Click Jobs section from the left side of the screen.

[image]

Check the message icon between the Developer Story and the Settings icon at the top-right corner of the Jobs screen.

[image].png